# Java8 sum up to a limit with streams

Tags: hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I have this LinkedHashMap:

```
myMap = {
  0 => 10,
  1 => 6,
  2 => 28,
  ...
}
int limit = 15;
```

What I'd want to do using streams is to sum (in order) the map values, and stop when the limit is reached, and return back the correspective index in the map (in this case 0).
Is there an elegant way with streams?

Comment: I don't see any. There is always a way to do it, but it will be contrived compare with a simple loop. Justa question, why do you use a LinkedHashMap instead of a List, since your keys are indices?

Comment: @Andrea, java 8 doesn't have the `takeWhile` operation to perform sth like *"stop when the limit is reached"*

Comment: What should be returned for, for example, 5 and 100 in your example?

Comment: `Map`s don’t have an index, they have keys. Why do you ask for an “elegant way with streams”, what’s wrong with “elegant ways without streams”?

Answer (score 1):

You could sum up to a limit like this

```
myMap.values().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a+b > limit ? a : a + b);
```

Comment: This will loop over the entire stream even if the limit is reached soon.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible via my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which extends the standard Stream API, though even with library it's not very elegant:

```
EntryStream.of(myMap) // like myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .prefix(
       (e1, e2) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e2.getKey(), e1.getValue() + e2.getValue()))
    .takeWhile(e -> e.getValue() < limit)
    .reduce((a, b) -> b)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Here we use two special StreamEx operations. One is `prefix` which lazily calculates running prefix (like `scanl` in Haskell). Here for two entries we select the key of the latter one and the sum of their values, creating a new entry. Next, we use `takeWhile` (which will also appear in Java 9 standard Stream API) to stop as soon as value exceeds the limit. Finally we reduce to the last found element and print it if its present, so we have not only index, but also final sum printed (if you need only index, add `.map(Entry::getKey)` step).

While such solution is moreless FP-ish I would not recommend it in general, because it's not very efficient and produces garbage (intermediate entries and boxed Integers), not to mention external library dependency. Use plain old for loop. It is efficient and easy-to-understand:

```
int sum = 0;
Integer lastKey = null;
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : myMap.entrySet()) {
    sum+=e.getValue();
    if(sum >= limit) break;
    lastKey = e.getKey();
}
if(lastKey != null) {
    System.out.println(lastKey);
}
```